# What will be the difference between adding the view programmatically vs using recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewgroup

There is a `canvas` and As a beginner, I have learned about `viewGroup` in android and how to add a `view` or multiple `views` in a `viewGroup` using either `xml` or programmatically using `addView`. We can add as many `view` we want to add and we can also increase the `height` of the `view` dynamically using `layoutParams`. While we can use `addView` or `setLayoutParams` to increase the height of the `canvas` as we add more `pages`, why should we use `recyclerView`?

From the `UI` perspective, everything seems equal here whether we say `increasing height` or `adding view` or `list of items`. Even though when we are `increasing the height`, there is a separator between each addition. However, the separator is not a major concern here. Basically, based on numbers of `pages` or `items` or `data`, we are `increasing the height` of the `canvas` view so that we can include and show all the `data`. These numbers of `pages` has been set to `14` currently but it can be increased without any limit and each `canvas board` can contain an unpredictable amount of data - may be hundreds of dots, a combination of lines, shapes, text, images and so on - which is fair. We are not limiting user to draw only certain amount of things on individual `canvas board`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While we can use addView or setLayoutParams to increase the height of
> the canvas as we add more pages, why should we use recyclerView?

Because RecyclerView is more efficient for large sets of data.

> From the UI perspective, everything seems equal here whether we say
> increasing height or adding view or list of items.

No, it's not. If you add a 1000 items to a `ViewGroup` it will try to draw 1000 items, dragging your app to a crawl at best, or crashing at worst.

If you add 1000 items to a `RecyclerView` it will draw however many will fit on screen.

> These numbers of pages has been set to 14 currently but it can be increased without any limit

Untrue. There is always a limit. It maybe large, but there are always limits. In this case, the limits are on RAM (how much data can the device hold in memory before it craps out).

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView is a powerful tool to efficiently display large sets of data with so many abilities such as caching and show items with animation.
Using RecylcedrThere is nothing to compare between RecyclerView and addView() cause their usage is different.
However i recommend you to read this article about how does RecyclerView Works.

[How Does RecyclerView Works](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-recyclerview-work-internally)

Comment: Thanks @Ali Babadi for taking time to help. I have gone through the official documentation of the recyclerView [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) and under [onCreateViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) section, I found this line: ```ViewGroup: The ViewGroup into which the new View will be added after it is bound to an adapter position.``` I understand, ```recyclerView``` is also using ```addView``` only.

Comment: If ```recyclerView``` is also using ```addView```, where are the difference and optimization?

Comment: `RecyclerView` uses cache strategy to retrieve the cached view from RecycledViewPool.